# Writable files in /proc directory of CentOS6.4

Tags: permissions, centos

While searching for files writeable by others, I'm coming across many files available in subdirectories of /proc/. I'm not much aware of the usage of these files, but curious to know whether if someone from the machine use "rm -rf /proc" or someone writes them for the purpose of corrupting them, then how it is going to harm the server. I'm running CentOS6.4

I have same situation for /selinux directory, here as well I have few files which are writable by others.

Thanks for your help on this.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should find that all the files in /proc, /sys and /selinux that are writable by normal users are actually specific to those users, or they do/control things that all users have access to.

For example, /proc/mounts is a symlink to /proc/self/mounts, and various processes owned by the current user will have writable files (eg: /proc/1234/*).

This is all normal unixy stuff and should present you with no problems, providing you haven't changed any defaults in how rights are granted to users.

The proc and sys directories are not actually part of the filesystem on disk, they are presented by the operating system in line with the old unix philosophy of "everything is a file".

I'd say you don't need to be concerned with what you've found, it all sounds quite normal. Feel free to present some specific filenames and permissions if you want to check any of them in particular.